# How to touch multiple records in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'd like to update the `updated_at` for a few records:

```
users = User.in_mailing_list
users.update_all(:updated_at => Time.now)
```

Is there a shortcut for the purpose, say something like a `users.touch_all` method?

Comment: I don't see any reason why you can't extend `ActiveRecord::Base` with whatever utility methods you like

Comment: @synapse avoid reinventing a wheel.

Comment: Rails 6 added [`touch_all`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-touch_all) in 2019, precisely what you were looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need touch `ActiveRelaton` records you have to use `update_all` method. It touches multiple records in a single transaction:

```
User.update_all(updated_at: Time.current)
User.where(active: true).update_all(active: false)
```

But if you have `Array` of records, in this case, you use only `each` with `update`

```
users.each { |user| user.update(active: true) }
```

the disadvantage of this case: for each `user` will be a separate transaction

Answer (score 12):

Not sure if rhernando's answer works in older versions of Ruby, but this is a much clearer method in my opinion and works in Ruby 2+

```
users.each(&:touch)
```

- NB. As mentioned in the comments this will cause N requests as opposed to using update_all which would do it in a single command.

Comment: This will issue _n_ queries unnecessarily. `users.update_all updated_at: Time.now` does it with 1 query.

Comment: It is necessary if you want the callbacks to fire on touch. API doco for update_all: "It does not instantiate the involved models and it does not trigger Active Record callbacks or validations."

Comment: @LucasNelson `touch` will not trigger them either. As per docs: `no validation is performed and only the after_touch, after_commit and after_rollback callbacks are executed.` ref: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-touch

Answer (score 8):

You can do it like this:

```
User.update_all({updated_at: Time.now}, {id: user_ids})
```

Note: The braces are required, otherwise it tries to set `updated_at` *and* `id`, instead of updating `updated_at` *where* `id` is in user_ids

Cheers!

Comment: This could also be written as `User.where(id: user_ids).update_all(updated_at: Time.now)`

Comment: Very useful, when you are doing a bulk update for a lot of models and want to trigger setting the updated_at timestamp! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure since when but the solution is much simpler:

```
users = User.in_mailing_list
users.touch_all
```

Or if you don't want to instantiate the user records:

```
users = User.in_mailing_list.touch_all
```

Comment: `touch_all` is only available starting in Rails 6: https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/Relation/touch_all

Comment: Which is what everyone should be using ;-)

Answer (score -2):

This should do it:

```
User.update(users, :updated_at => Time.now)
```